# NavHostFragment not accessible from fragment in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I tried to access `NavController` from the home fragment but had no success. Spent the whole day but still had no success at all. The app crashes in `HomeFragment` in this line of code:

```
navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Here is the code that I have implemented:

**HomeFragmnet**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    private var itemList: MutableList<Home?> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.homeRecyclerView)
        return root
    }
}
```

This is xml implementation of **nav_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="fi.gambitlabs.pworker.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

</navigation>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var navView: NavigationView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Disable dark mode
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

**Error Logs**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fi.gambitlabs.pworker, PID: 12300
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fi.gambitlabs.pworker/fi.gambitlabs.pworker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in fi.gambitlabs.pworker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in fi.gambitlabs.pworker:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14 in fi.gambitlabs.pworker:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #19 in fi.gambitlabs.pworker:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19 in fi.gambitlabs.pworker:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3375)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:366)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at *emphasized text*androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at fi.gambitlabs.pworker.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:30)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at fi.gambitlabs.Pworker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PWorker.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.PWorker.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
}
```

Have spent lots of time trying to find a solution on google but nothing works and now I am stuck. It crashes when trying to access requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment) in HomeFragment but no crashes with the same code in MainActivity as seen on code snippet.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: Have you tried moving the navController reading to the `onViewCreated` method?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I tried moving to onViewCreated but no success.

Comment: If you check the XML sample here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer, they have the `nav_host_fragment` as child of DrawerLayout, but in your activity_main.xml there is not

Comment: Thanks. Will try this and give update.

Comment: Well I found that, I have added nav_host_fragment. In activity_main.xml have added app_bar_main.xml which include @layout/content_main. content_main has nav_host_fragment. I have updated my code with app_bar_main.xml and also the dependencies. Actually, its strange that this way of adding navhostfragment works in another project but not here at all. Dont know if kotlin version can cause such issue.

Comment: Actually, this was created with the android studio default navigation drawer project template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to access NavController from the home fragment but had no success.

You can't access the `NavController` because you try to access it before the `setContentView()` of the activity get finished; i.e you are trying to access a resource `R.id.nav_host_fragment` that doesn't exist yet.

And the reason because the `HomeFragment` is initially hosted by the activity, and it's a part of the activity layout; and in order to draw the fragment on the activity, it needs to take a chance first to get the fragment layout before returning the entire layout with `setContentView()`

To verify that add the below log messages in the activity (`MainActivity`) & `HomeFragment`:

Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // .... Code omitted

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onCreate: BEFORE setContentView()")

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onCreate: AFTER setContentView()")

        // .... Code omitted

        Log.d(TAG, "MainActivity onCreate: END")

    }
```

Fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    // .... Code omitted

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        Log.d(TAG, "HomeFragment onCreateView: START")

        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        // .... Code omitted

        Log.d(TAG, "HomeFragment onCreateView: END")

        return root
    }
```

The outcome:

```
 D/LOG_TAG: MainActivity onCreate: BEFORE setContentView()
 D/LOG_TAG: HomeFragment onCreateView: START
 D/LOG_TAG: HomeFragment onCreateView: END
 D/LOG_TAG: MainActivity onCreate: AFTER setContentView()
 D/LOG_TAG: MainActivity onCreate: END
```

**How to solve this:**

You can set the `navController` in lifecycle methods beyond `onCreateView()` & `onViewCreated()` of the `HomeFragment` like in `onStart()`, or `onResume()`

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    // .... Code omitted

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val navController = requireActivity().findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    }
```

Comment: Well I found that, I have added nav_host_fragment. In activity_main.xml have added app_bar_main.xml which include @layout/content_main. content_main has nav_host_fragment. I have updated my code with app_bar_main.xml and also the dependencies. Actually, its strange that this way of adding navhostfragment works in another project but not here at all. Dont know if kotlin version can cause such issue.

Comment: Actually, this was created with the android studio default navigation drawer project template.

Comment: @skJosh The reason is that the activity layout is not inflated yet. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you haven't included **content_main.xml** in your **activity_main.xml**

Comment: Well, am new to android. I looked into the way to include content_main.xml into activity_main.xml but couldn't find the way. Any hint?

Comment: the same way you did 
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

in layout attribute just give  layout="@layout/content_main"

Comment: Actually I found that, I have added content_main. In activity_main.xml have added app_bar_main.xml which include @layout/content_main. content_main has nav_host_fragment. I have updated my code with app_bar_main.xml and also the dependencies. Actually, its strange that this way of adding navhostfragment works in another project but not here at all. Dont know if kotlin version can cause such issue.

Comment: Actually, this was created with the android studio default navigation drawer project template.

Comment: did my answer solved your problem? you just have to understand that without attaching(inflating) any layout to Fragment/activity they can not access it. So there are two ways to do.. First is via XML and second is inflate at class level.

happy coding !